# derivative of logarithmic arcsine yields unexpected result

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

So, I begin with knowing that:
$$ \sin{x} = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i} = L,~\text{s.t}~i=\sqrt{-1}$$
And so continuing to solve for $x$, yielding the standard result:
$$ \arcsin{L} = -i \ln{[Li + \sqrt{1 - L^2}]},~\text{assm. principal branch}$$
Then I attempt to find $\frac{d}{dL} \arcsin{L}$ from the leading definition, and I come up with:
$$\frac{d\arcsin{L}}{dL} = -i\left[(Li + \sqrt{1 - L^2})' * (\sqrt{1 - L^2} - Li)\right]
\\ = -i\left[i + \frac{L}{(1 - L^2)^{3/2}}\right]\left[\sqrt{1 - L^2} - Li\right]
\\ = -i \left[i\sqrt{1 - L^2} + L + \frac{L}{1 - L^2} - \frac{Li}{(1 - L^2)^{3/2}}\right]
\\ = \sqrt{1 - L^2} - Li - \frac{Li}{1 - L^2} - \frac{L}{(1 - L^2)^{3/2}}$$

Which, seems completely different to the regular result I find on the internet of:
$$ \frac{d\arcsin{x}}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}$$
I've tried to look for a similar derivation, but to no avail, so I wonder whether differentiating the complex arcsine function is intended to give a different answer to its (presumably) real counterpart? I'm sorry if it's obvious, but I've spent a few hours on this and I seem to be making mistakes in and out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in the second step of differentiation.

$$\begin{align*}\frac{d\arcsin{L}}{dL}&= -i\left[(Li + \sqrt{1 - L^2})' * (\sqrt{1 - L^2} - Li)\right]
\\&= -i\left[i \color{red}-\frac{L}{(1 - L^2)^{\color{red}{1/2}}}\right]\left[\sqrt{1 - L^2} - Li\right]\end{align*}$$which yields the correct result.

Comment: goodness, thank you

Comment: You are welcome!